# How Inno Setup Detects OpenGL Version

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

```pascal
function LoadLibraryEx(lpLibFileName: string; hFile: THandle; dwFlags: DWORD): THandle;
    external 'LoadLibraryEx{#AW}@kernel32.dll stdcall';
function GetProcAddress(hModule: THandle; lpProcName: string): LongWord;
    external 'GetProcAddress@kernel32.dll stdcall';

function gluGetString(Name: Cardinal): PAnsiChar;
    external 'gluGetString@opengl32.dll stdcall';

function GetOpenGLVersion: string;
var
    hLib: THandle;
    glVersionFunction: function(Name: Cardinal): PAnsiChar;
    Version: PAnsiChar;
begin
    hLib := LoadLibraryEx('{sys}\opengl32.dll', 0, 0);
    if  hLib <> 0 then
    begin
        //@glVersionFunction := GetProcAddress(hLib, 'gluGetString');
        //if Assigned(glVersionFunction) then
        //    Version := glVersionFunction($1F02);
        
        MsgBox('LoadLibraryEx success', mbInformation, MB_OK);
    end;

    MsgBox('GetOpenGLVersion: ' + ExpandConstant('{sys}\opengl32.dll'), mbInformation, MB_OK);
    Version := gluGetString($1F02); // GL_VERSION
    MsgBox('GetOpenGLVersion: ' + Version, mbInformation, MB_OK);
    Result := string(Version);
end;
```

[image]

Using external will cause errors during runtime.
Unable to compile successfully using `GetProcAddress`.

I don't know how function pointers should be correctly represented and called in Inno Setup.

Answer (score 0):

```pascal
[Code]

const
  PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL = $00000020;
  PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW = $00000004;
  PFD_TYPE_RGBA = $00000000;
  PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER = $00000001;
  PFD_MAIN_PLANE = $00000000;
  GL_VERSION = $1F02;

type
    HDC = THandle;

    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR = record
        nSize: Word;
        nVersion: Word;
        dwFlags: Cardinal;
        iPixelType: Byte;
        cColorBits: Byte;
        cRedBits: Byte;
        cRedShift: Byte;
        cGreenBits: Byte;
        cGreenShift: Byte;
        cBlueBits: Byte;
        cBlueShift: Byte;
        cAlphaBits: Byte;
        cAlphaShift: Byte;
        cAccumBits: Byte;
        cAccumRedBits: Byte;
        cAccumGreenBits: Byte;
        cAccumBlueBits: Byte;
        cAccumAlphaBits: Byte;
        cDepthBits: Byte;
        cStencilBits: Byte;
        cAuxBuffers: Byte;
        iLayerType: Byte;
        bReserved: Byte;
        dwLayerMask: Cardinal;
        dwVisibleMask: Cardinal;
        dwDamageMask: Cardinal;
    end;

function glGetString(Name: Cardinal): PAnsiChar;
    external 'glGetString@opengl32.dll stdcall';
function wglCreateContext(hdc: HDC): THandle;
    external 'wglCreateContext@opengl32.dll';
function wglMakeCurrent(hdc: HDC; hglrc: THandle): BOOL;
    external 'wglMakeCurrent@opengl32.dll';
function wglDeleteContext(hdc: HDC): BOOL;
    external 'wglDeleteContext@opengl32.dll';
function ChoosePixelFormat(hdc: HDC; const pfd: PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR): Integer;
    external 'ChoosePixelFormat@gdi32.dll';
function SetPixelFormat(hdc: HDC; iPixelFormat: Integer; const pfd: PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR): BOOL;
    external 'SetPixelFormat@gdi32.dll';
function GetDC(hWnd: HWND): HDC;
    external 'GetDC@user32.dll';
function ReleaseDC(hWnd: HWND; hDc: HDC): Integer;
    external 'ReleaseDC@user32.dll';

function SplitStringInternal(Text: String; Separator: String): TArrayOfString;
var
    i, p: Integer;
    Dest: TArrayOfString;
begin
    i := 0;
    repeat
        SetArrayLength(Dest, i + 1);
        p := Pos(Separator, Text);
        if p > 0 then begin
            Dest[i] := Copy(Text, 1, p - 1);
            Text := Copy(Text, p + Length(Separator), Length(Text));
            i := i + 1;
        end else begin
            Dest[i] := Text;
            Text := '';
        end;
    until Length(Text)=0;
    Result := Dest
end;

function VersionToInt(version: string): Integer;
var
    p: Integer;
    realVersion: string;
    versionArray: TArrayOfString;
begin
    p := Pos('-', version);
    if p > 0 then begin
        realVersion := Copy(version, 1, p - 1);
    end else begin
        realVersion := version;
    end;

    versionArray := SplitStringInternal(realVersion, '.');
    if GetArrayLength(versionArray) <> 3 then
    begin
        Result := 300
        exit;
    end;

    Result := StrToIntDef(versionArray[0], 0) * 100 + StrToIntDef(versionArray[1], 0) * 10 + StrToIntDef(versionArray[2], 0);
end;

function GetOpenGLVersion: Integer;
var
    Hdc: HDC;
    Pfd: PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR;
    PixelFormat: Integer;
    Hglrc: THandle;
    strOpenGLVersion: string;
begin
    Hdc := GetDC(0);

    Pfd.nSize := 40;
    Pfd.nVersion := 1;
    Pfd.dwFlags := PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL or PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW;
    Pfd.iPixelType := PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    Pfd.cColorBits := 32;
    Pfd.cDepthBits := 24;
    Pfd.cStencilBits := 8;
    Pfd.iLayerType := PFD_MAIN_PLANE;
    Pfd.cRedBits := 0;
    Pfd.cRedShift := 0;
    Pfd.cGreenBits := 0;
    Pfd.cGreenShift := 0;
    Pfd.cBlueBits := 0;
    Pfd.cBlueShift := 0;
    Pfd.cAlphaBits := 0;
    Pfd.cAlphaShift := 0;
    Pfd.cAccumBits := 0;
    Pfd.cAccumRedBits := 0;
    Pfd.cAccumGreenBits := 0;
    Pfd.cAccumBlueBits := 0;
    Pfd.cAccumAlphaBits := 0;
    Pfd.cAuxBuffers := 0;
    Pfd.bReserved := 0;
    Pfd.dwLayerMask := 0;
    Pfd.dwVisibleMask := 0;
    Pfd.dwDamageMask := 0;
    
    PixelFormat := ChoosePixelFormat(Hdc, Pfd);
    SetPixelFormat(Hdc, PixelFormat, Pfd);

    Hglrc := wglCreateContext(Hdc);
    wglMakeCurrent(Hdc, Hglrc);

    strOpenGLVersion := glGetString(GL_VERSION);

    wglMakeCurrent(0, 0);
    wglDeleteContext(Hglrc);

    ReleaseDC(0, Hdc);

    Result := VersionToInt(strOpenGLVersion);
end;
```

Comment: Is this an answer or additional information for your question? If the former, please add some explanation; if the latter, please edit your question and delete this.

Comment: Former. This is the inspiration obtained from the C program. By using the function name in a C program, you can obtain OpenGL version information.